# Automatically answer input prompt of an exe started within a windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an `InputPromptAutomation.exe` that prompts for a user input when started and closes if the user input is `s`:

```
C:\>AutomateInputPrompt\InputPromptAutomation.exe
Input 's' to stop the application:
s
C:\>
```

My Problem: I want to automate the startup of the .exe, such that I can start it by double-clicking a `StartInputPrompt.bat`. How can I automatically pass the `s` input, such that `InputPromptAutomation.exe` starts AND exits upon executing `StartInputPrompt.bat`?

Comment: `echo s|AutomateInputPrompt\InputPromptAutomation.exe` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo s | AutomateInputPrompt\InputPromptAutomation.exe
```

Here's an example of piping Dir into a new CMD instance

```
Echo dir | cmd /k
```

Put S then Enter in a file.

```
AutomateInputPrompt\InputPromptAutomation.exe < file.txt
```

Here's an example of doing a `dir` then a `Type c:\windows\win.ini`

File.txt (remember to press enter after the last line). This IS NOT a batch file (even though it is identical to one because I'm use CMD as a sample program).

```
dir
type c:\windows\win.ini
```

Then type

```
cmd /k < file.txt
```

This assumes the program is reading from StdIn, as most, but not all console programs do. EG when you see `Press any key to continue` the program is NOT reading stdin.

Start is an internal command name. Do not name batch files `start` as it will cause problems under some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are the two code snippets alternatives? What do I have to put into file.txt?

Comment: Whatever you want to send to the program. They are alternatives but files allow many lines to be sent. Make sure you end each line with an enter.

Comment: i.e. I can just list a sequence of inputs in the file and pass it to the command?

Comment: Yes. Look at the edit I made. And I'm about to make another.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works with my example! Btw: I took heed of your advice and changed the bat name in my original post.